# Make a MediaSource in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, media-source

I went though this : [How to use MediaRecorder as MediaSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860029/how-to-use-mediarecorder-as-mediasource). However I still don’t achieve to get a MediaSource work in Safari (it is not compatible) or find an alternative. So how to play my segmented media (many webm videos) in Safari and keep current code for Chrome/Firefox that works well?

Thanks.